# C# Control.Invoke a method group

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I am using threads to run long operations in my program's UI so that it doesn't lock up. However, in those tasks I need to update controls, which is impossible not from the thread they were created on. It is suggested to use control.BeginInvoke(Delegate) to execute the method you want.

However, to do that you have to declare a delegate type and only then you can call them.

So, it goes like this: if I want to execute method void Update(), i have to go:

```
delegate void CallbackVoid();
void Update() {...}

...(in task code)...
this.BeginInvoke(new CallbackVoid(Update));
```

This is rather tiresome to do for every single method out there. Can't I just somehow do it naturally, like:

```
void Update() {...}    
this.BeginInvoke(Update);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: **WORKS FOR WPF!!!**

You can use short syntax with anonymous methods, without even declaring your methods

```
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new MethodInvoker(() =>   
                {
                   //Your Update code
                }));
```

Comment: How is that different from control.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
{/* update control here */})); ? Which is better?

Comment: @Arie Both are correct, but not other. MSDN says: "The delegate can be an instance of EventHandler, in which case the sender parameter will contain this control, and the event parameter will contain EventArgs.Empty. The delegate can also be an instance of MethodInvoker, or any other delegate that takes a void parameter list. A call to an EventHandler or MethodInvoker delegate will be faster than a call to another type of delegate"

Comment: @voo: Actually this *isn't* correct for Windows Forms, which is what the question appears to be about...

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, you are right as always. I saw no winforms tag, and missed "this" word :( I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

One option which simplified things is to add an extension method:

```
public static void BeginInvokeAction(this Control control, Action action)
{
    control.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
this.BeginInvokeAction(action);
```

The reason this works is that we're now providing a concrete delegate type for the compiler to convert the method group to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    if (this.controlname.InvokeRequired && !this.controlname.IsDisposed)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                        {
                            //Update control on GUI here!

    }));
    else if(!this.controlname.IsDisposed)
   {
                           //AND here!
   }
```

Comment: This is substantially *more* code, not less, and has no advantages over any other solution.  The whole idea is that the OP *knows* he's not in the UI thread; there's no need to check, and he knows that the controls aren't disposed (if not it would honestly be better to just crash so you could find/fix the bug, rather than silently continuing on).

Answer (score 0):

`BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, `Invoke` is synchronous, which one you use depends on what you're trying to do.  If you need the call to complete before you move on, then you want synchronous calls.

Here's my favorite construct for synchronous invokes:

```
 static void InvokeIfRequired(Control control, Action action)
 {
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

Used:

```
void MyTestFunction()
{
    InvokeIfRequired(myControl, () =>
        {
            MyFunction();
            MyOtherFunction();
        });

    // Or more simply:
    InvokeIfRequired(myControl, () => MyFunction());
}
```

There is a little overhead in the creation of the Action, but it simplifies the code quite a bit to not have to think about the details everywhere.